# PUT query parameters not making it to server in PHP curl request

Tags: php, curl, put

I am attempting to send a PUT request using PHP and curl and my query parameters do not seem to be making it to the API. The logs verify that the request is coming in as a PUT but the parameters are not making it. I've followed every example I could find on the internet that describes how to build the query parameters building it manually and using the http_build_query function. I then add the parameters using the  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS value. Am I missing something needed for query params with a PUT request?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the POST request, the PUT request requires to specify the Content-Length that you are going to send to the server. Here is an example:

```
// data to be sent
$post_data = "...soem data";

// so that you get response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// this is must for doing PUT
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: ' . strlen($post_data)));

// Doing PUT
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data );
```

If you still have problem after this, run the curl by enabling the verbose mode and it will show you the debug msg on curl's operation:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```